# Which parts of a laptop can be damaged by drop impact?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, macbook

I have Macbook pro late 2013 with SSD. 1-2 times I dropped it inside bag (with protection) from about 30-40 CM while it's off. I know that when laptop with HDD, there is chance that HDD can be damaged. What I want to know is, when it's SSD what part else can be damaged when dropped? Is there anything to worry about?

I need detailed answer. And very worried. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: TT13, you need to edit your title, it's misleading, I think what your real question actually is about SSD drive's durability. If this is really what you're question is about, its largely opinion based that will not give you a pin point answer. I will tell you this, SSD drives can take quite a beating, people drop them from higher distances and a story of someone taking a bat to it and nothing happened to the drive. They have no moving parts, so they can take quite a beating as opposed to SATA or older IDE drivers which have moving parts instead.

Comment: You are dropping electronics its not good for it.  SSD has no moving parts.  But there are mechanical parts ( the fan ) that can be damaged.  Stop dropping your bag.

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides a support diagnostics utility for your laptop. See the link below for full details.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5781

### Using Apple Diagnostics

Apple Diagnostics is a great way to check your Mac computer’s hardware. Apple Diagnostics helps to identify the potential source of a hardware issue and provides first steps to try and resolve it. Apple Diagnostics will also help you get in touch with Apple Support for further assistance.

### Before You Begin

- Important: If your Mac was introduced before June 2013, you will
  use Apple Hardware Test rather than Apple Diagnostics. See
  Intel-based Macs: Using Apple Hardware Test for instructions.
- Consider doing some preliminary troubleshooting to determine if
  your issue is related to hardware. You can try to determine if the
  cause of your issue is related to hardware or software by following
  Isolating issues in Mac OS X. Apple Diagnostics can help determine
  which hardware component may be causing the issue.
- Before starting Apple Diagnostics, be sure to disconnect all external devices except
  the keyboard, mouse, display, and Ethernet adapter. Also disconnect
  any external optical drives.
- You should have an Internet connection
  before starting Apple Diagnostics. This will enable Apple Diagnostics
  to recommend support resources. Additionally, if Apple Diagnostics is
  not found on the internal startup volume, an Internet-based version
  starts up instead. You can still run Apple Diagnostics without an
  Internet connection, but no results will be uploaded to Apple and no
  connection to Apple Support web pages will occur.  If you are
  testing a Mac notebook, perform the following additional steps:

  - To prevent your computer from shutting down during testing, connect
    the correct wattage AC power adapter to an AC power outlet.
  - Set up your computer on a hard, flat, stable work surface that allows for
    adequate air circulation under and around the computer (such as a
    desk, table, or counter).

### To start Apple Diagnostics:

- Turn off your computer if it is on by choosing Shut Down from the
  Apple menu.
- Press the power button to turn on your computer.
- Immediately press and hold the D key until Apple Diagnostics begins.
- If you previously selected a language for the computer, a "Checking your Mac" screen will appear in that language.

[image]

If you have not selected a language for the computer, a language selection menu will appear. Select a language and Apple Diagnostics will begin. ​

[image]

- The basic Apple Diagnostics test takes approximately 2-3 minutes to complete. As the diagnostic runs, a progress bar indicates the time remaining in the test.  ￼

[image]

- To exit Apple Diagnostics, click Restart or Shut Down at the bottom of the screen.
- To change the language used by Apple Diagnostics, press Command-L after the test completes. Note: A complete list of keyboard shortcuts is listed later in this article.

Comment: `SSD what part else can be damaged when dropped? Is there anything to worry about?` Pretty sure he's only asking about SSD drive.

Comment: @Sickest AHD tests more than just the hard drive

Comment: its a great answer, All i'm trying to say is i think his question is more of an opinion based answer specifically regarding SSD drives vs SATA/IDE drivers that have mechanical pieces inside. This doesn't address that at all. Right?

Comment: `SSD what part **else** can be damaged when dropped? Is there anything to worry about?` The "else" would lead me to believe that he wants to know what else apart from the SSD could be damaged by blunt force impact. I understand where you're coming from, but that specific wording is most likely why he has chosen to answer in this way.